# Celery Beat Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, django, celery, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to setup celery beat on Elastic Beanstalk. The normal tasks are working perfectly fine, but the beat scheduler seems to have some issues. It is a permission issue and seeing that I am new to EB I have no idea how to get this to work.

When I SSH into the app and enter:

```
celery -A project beat -l info
```

I get the following error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/run/celery/celery-beat.pid'
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: put `sudo` before celery, you may need to superadmin to use celery command in the EB.

Comment: I then get htis: sudo: celery: command not found

Comment: Then how the normal tasks are working fine? You didn't setup celery right, how did you install the celery, did you use virtualenv? You have to make sure the celery package is in the your environment path!

Comment: Celery is fine, it runs 100% on heroku